# Timeout for individual tests in NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I'm aware that there is a Timeout attribute in NUnit. My problem is that the unit tests actually spawn a new process which, if frozen, is never killed by NUnit. How can I implement a timeout which will actually get rid of the rogue process?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use timeout for assertion, instead of timeout for whole test method:

```
Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected).After(5000, 50));
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. You can clean up the thread after that.

Comment: As good as this is, I couldn't make it work with my scenario - spawn another process, pop a dialogue up and NUnit will never kill it, unless you click the button.

Comment: Well, thus you are not doing acceptance tests, I'd advice you to use something like
1) White http://white.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=85842&ANCHOR
2) NUnit Forms http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/

Both are good for creating windows and pressing buttons.

Comment: I do agree that this would be a good approach if I want to test that a dialogue has popped up, etc. The above was just an example.

Comment: Mmmm... another thing you can use - just kill that process manually in [TearDown] method.

Comment: I've already given you best answer, although I can't get to the [TearDown]. It just stays in the call and NUnit is completely ignorant about all the timeouts. I'll try to put down a small example to show what I mean.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** The accepted answer is a better one.

If your test eventually times out (albeit later than you hope), you can always use the `MaxTime` attribute: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=maxtime&r=2.5.1 and clean up the thread yourself:

```
[Test, Maxtime(2000)]
public void TimedTest()
{
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, your best option might be to implement your own timing mechanism. Use a timer (or a busy while loop) and if the timeout is exceeded, then kill the process (maybe in the ShutDown method if it's generic across tests) and signal failure.

NUnit timeouts don't have any events that allow you to run code after the test times out. You have to roll your own, it looks like.

Comment: Most probably I'll have to go the second path. Just as an example - if the spawned process pops a message on a build machine - nobody there to click it - the NUnit timeout will never kick in. So it has to be some timing mechanism of my own.

Answer (score 4):

```
[Test, Timeout(2000)]
public void PotentiallyLongRunningTest()
{
    ...
}
```

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5.1 :

> The TimeoutAttribute is used to specify a timeout value in milliseconds for a test case. If the test case runs longer than the time specified it is immediately cancelled and reported as a failure, with a message indicating that the timeout was exceeded.
>
> The attribute may also be specified on a fixture or assembly, in which case it indicates the default timeout for any subordinate test cases.

Answer (score 0):

OK. After I've tried all the features built in NUnit and failed to achieve what I needed, I did the following: I've added a timer which is being set in a function attributed [SetUp] on a fixture level and thus is called before each Test. If the timer ticks before the test has finished, I just do the clean-up in the timer callback.

Answer (score 0):

In new NUnit versions (could not find out when it was added in the [changelog](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/release-notes/framework.html)), you can [use the `CancelAfterAttribute`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/cancelafter.html?q=timeout) ([current source code](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/ac561dd273b1ec71582603a037e295328e41ff6f/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/CancelAfterAttribute.cs)). See the linked docs, it works very simple by taking a `CancellationToken` as a parameter that is cancelled after the timeout:

```cs
[Test, CancelAfter(2000)]
public void RunningTestUntilCanceled(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        /* */
    }
}

[CancelAfter(2000)]
[TestCase("http://server1")]
[TestCase("http://server2")]
public async Task PotentiallyLongRunningTest(string uri, CancellationToken token)
{
    HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    HttpContent content = CreateContent();
    await client.PostAync(uri, content, token);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri, token);
    /* */
}
```

Edit: [Given the git repo](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/commit/ecadfd64682efca1bef43e27cb05176778b666de) the feature was likely added in NUnit 4, [which this doc seems to confirm](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/Towards-NUnit4.html#cooperative-cancellation).